# Definir un elemento en css mediante su atributo

Tags: html, css, atributos

Tengo un `<input type="text" placeholder="Introduce tu nombre">` y otro `<input type="submit" value="Enviar">`, y no le quiero poner el atributo `class`, sino que quiero probar definiendo el de `text` por su atributo `type`. Dejo el codigo:

#### HTML

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Introduce tu nombre">
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Enviar">
```

#### CSS

```
input <type"text"> {
padding: 7px;
}
```

Se que lo del `<type"text">` no funciona, ya que lo he probado, asi que mi pregunta es ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Gracias de antemano y un saludo**texto en negrita**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se cual sea tu propósito pero claro que puedes.

```css
input{
  padding: 10px;
}

input[type="text"]{
  background-color: #d2d2d2;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Introduce tu nombre">
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Enviar">
```

PD: Es mejor usar clases.

Comment: Si, solo era por probar, a ver si se podia hacer... Nada mas

Answer (score 1):

PUEDES usar IDs

```css
#TEXT {
padding: 10px;
border-radius: 15px;
border: 4px solid #ff9f33;
}

#TEXT:focus {
  border: 4px solid #002233;
}

#btn-enviar {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #ff9f33;
  background-color: #ff9f33;
  color: #002233;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition 0.3s;
  border-radius: 15px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#btn-enviar:hover {
  transition: 0.3s;
  background-color: #002233;
  color: #ff9f33;
}
```

```html
<input id="TEXT" type="text" placeholder="Introduce tu nombre">
<br><br>
<input id="btn-enviar" type="submit" value="Enviar">
```